# How many $5$-letter "words" can be formed from the letters A through H, without repeating letters or including the subword BAD?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

Can someone please help me understand this problem?

> Consider all 5 letter "words" made from the letters A through H.
> (Recall, words are just strings of letters, not necessarily actual English
> words.) How many of the words containing no repeats also do not contain the sub-word BAD?

The answer is $(8\times 7\times 6\times 5\times 4) - 3(5\times 4)$, where the first term is the total words with no repeats and the second term is the total "bad" words.

I understand how to get the first term, but I can´t understand how to get all the words with subword "bad".

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the subword "BAD" as a single entity "X".

Your 5 letter words will then be reduced to a 3 letter word.

There are 3 positions to put "X" in: X * *, * X *, * * X.

As you have already used 3 letters, there are 5 and 4 ways to fill in the first and second * respectively.

This gives the answer $3 \times (5\times 4)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Complement Principle ie. Count all possible "words" using letter A to H such that no two letter is repeated twice. You can use formula for n - Permutation. Now we have to count "bad words" ie. Arrangements which we do not wish to count. Now, our "bad word" must contain the subword "BAD". Now, that means we have to choose only two letters. Note that "B", "A" and "D" already occurs once. Thus, a "bad word" is either one of these three forms: XYBAD, BADXY or XBADY. Now subtract the total number of "bad words" from "total number of permutations".

Comment: X and Y belong to the set {C, E F, G, H} such that X is not equal to. Y.